# Encoding QR Code on ZOS platform

Tags: qr-code, mainframe, zos

My question is for QR Code support on the ZOS platform.  We have legacy systems that produce many printed documents and mailings.  I have been tasked with the challenge of developing a called routine that can receive a 200 byte string of variable data and return the encoded data for a QR Code.  I’ve walk through a series of mathematical calculation required to encode the data in the algorithm for printing with a barcode font.

I wondered if someone has already tackled this task on the mainframe.
 I am looking for short cuts on the mathematical encoding portion in COBOL.  I have seen several applications out there that were designed for other platforms and other languages. Has anyone experimented with creating QR Codes on the Mainframe or know of any dynamic processes that can handle the calculation portion of the encoding?

Comment: Anything useful from an internet search?

Comment: Why does it have to be in COBOL?  Can you call a routine written in Metal C that implements the QR code?

Comment: The goal is to build a reusable routine that can be maintained by the majority of the team. I don't have any knowledge of "Metal C". This where the COBOL language is preferred.  I am sure that I can make use of REXX or EZtrieve, but they are not the preferred method.

Comment: Late to the party, but we just helped a customer with something similar. Instead of trying to write our own QR library, we ported the open-source libqrencode to z/OS...there were a few small issues, but mostly it was just a matter of getting the source on z/OS and building it there. This gave us a library of callable routines that can do just about anything you like with QR codes, and while the actual QR encoding isn't written in COBOL (it's C), it's well-maintained open source so you don't need to worry about maintaining it.

Comment: Here is a QR Code generator that is delivered as open source in multiple languages.  https://github.com/nayuki/QR-Code-generator with an MIT license